# How to reference a specific field from different collection when building a mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm building schema (Meal) and I want one of the fields (meat_name) in this schema to be taken from different field (meatName) of different schema (Meat).
I'm aware to the populate method, but It referencing to the entire collection and I want to reference to specific field.

```
    -Meat Schema-
```

```
    const meatSchema= new Schema({
  MeatName: String,
  MeatDescription: String,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Meat", meatSchema);
```

```
    -Meal Schema-
```

```
    const mealSchema= new Schema({
  mealName: String,
  mealPrice: Number,
  meat_name: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Meat" /*populate method return the entire collection, but I want just the meatName field in that collection */,
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Meal", mealSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can achieve this by using `virtual` (read more here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html)

As per your question -

```
mealSchema.virtual('meat_name', {
  ref: 'Meat', // ref model to use
  localField: 'meat_name', // field in mealSchema
  foreignField: 'MeatName', // The field in meatSchema. 
});
```

`MeatName` in `meatSchema` can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a particular field to populate using SELECT options
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths

For your question:

```
await mealSchemafind().populate({ path: 'meat_name', select: '_id MeatName' })
```